# How to set the keep me logged in box to true in Mediawiki Special:UserLogin

Tags: mediawiki

Can you force (or at least prompt) new users to keep themselves logged in?

In order to reduce the likelihood of losing work, I would like the Special:UserLogin page to appear as [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use `$wgDefaultUserOptions['rememberpassword'] = 1`. See [$wgDefaultUserOptions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgDefaultUserOptions) (and also [$wgHiddenPrefs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgHiddenPrefs)).

Answer (score 4):

(MediaWiki 1.31.0, edited 2020) Add to LocalSettings.php:

```
$wgHooks['AuthChangeFormFields'][] = function ($requests, $fieldInfo, &$formDescriptor, $action) {
  $formDescriptor['rememberMe'] = ['type' => 'check', 'default' => true];
  return true;
};
```

See [Hooks/AuthChangeFormFields](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/AuthChangeFormFields) and [HTMLForm](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/HTMLForm).

Comment: That looks like it might work.   Where did you get this code?   Can you link to a source or to documentation from which you pieced to together?

Comment: Don't forget to add a `'label' => 'Remember me'` property or the field wont be labeled.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer will now throw fatal exception on Special:CreateAccount if anybody attempts account creation. You have to define the HTML form class. Something like this:

```php
// Check the password "remember me" box by default (sitewide)
$wgHooks['AuthChangeFormFields'][] = function ($requests, $fieldInfo, &$formDescriptor, $action) {
    $formDescriptor['rememberMe'] = ['type' => 'check', 'default' => true ];
    return true;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

We wanted to change the "Keep me logged in" (in German it's "Angemeldet bleiben") default as well, but overwriting the complete array `$formDescriptor['rememberMe']` also removed the label text. Here it seems better to set type and default value seperately in `LocalSettings.php` (using MediaWiki 1.35.6):

```php
// Check the password "remember me" box by default (sitewide)
$wgHooks['AuthChangeFormFields'][] = function ($requests, $fieldInfo, &$formDescriptor, $action) {
    $formDescriptor['rememberMe']['type'] = 'check';
    $formDescriptor['rememberMe']['default'] = true;
    return true;
};
```